# Error message using keras in Rstudio, Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: in user code:

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I'm hoping someone can help me here.  I'm having great difficulty using the keras package in Rstudio.

I have been following the ISLR2 book, chapter 10, and I'm trying to do problem 7, which has to do with the default dataset.

When I run it, I get the following message:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: in user code:

```
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:853 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:842 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:835 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
```

I have absolutely no idea what this means, to put it mildly.

Here is the code I am using:

```
### getting our testid
default=Default
n=nrow(default)
testid.7=sample(1:n, ntest)

x=default[ ,c(2, 3, 4)]
y=default$default


xtrain=as.data.frame(x[-testid.7, ])
ytrain=y[-testid.7]

## converting out  y, which is the default response, to categorical

y_train_cat=rep(NA, length(y_train))

for (i in 1:length(y_train)) {
  if (y_train[i]=="Yes") {
    y_train_cat[i]=1
  } else {y_train_cat[i]=0}
}

y_train_cat



### Converting the student variable into a categorical variable
trainstudent=xtrain$student
student_cat=rep(NA, length(trainstudent))

for (i in 1:length(trainstudent)) {
  if (trainstudent[i]=="Yes") {
    student_cat[i]=1  } else {student_cat[i]=0}
}

xtrain_mod=as.data.frame(cbind(student_cat, xtrain$balance, xtrain$income))

## Fitting our neural network
modnn.7=keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units=10, activation="relu", input_shape=c(3)) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate=0.4) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1, activation='softmax')


modnn.7%>%compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
                metrics =  'accuracy'
)


history <- modnn.7 %>% fit (
  xtrain_mod, 
  y_train_cat, 
  epochs = 200, 
  batch_size = 50
  )
```

If anyone has any insight that would be great.  I am an MS student who has been using R for a few years, but this is my only experience with the keras package, so obviously I am very new to it.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is the entire message I get from the error

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: in user code:

```
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:853 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:842 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
C:\MINICO~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:835 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
```

Comment: Can please you post the output of `reticulate::py_last_error()` and/or make the example self-contained using [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org). (`dput()` might be helpful). Right now it's not possible to copy-paste your code and get the same error since we can't know what `Default` is.

Comment: Default is the default dataset from the ISLR2 package.  It is part of that package, so you can pull it up after installing the ISLR2 library.

Comment: I will try your suggestions to make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciated!

Comment: When I run the reticulate above I got quite a bit of output.   The first part of it is $type
[1] "ValueError"

Comment: I'll be happy to take a look again after you edit your example to use reprex :)